# C: pointer being freed was not allocated -- when calling free

Tags: c

My function:

```
Shot *shot_collide(Shot *shot)
{
    Shot *moving, *remaining;
    remaining=NULL;

    moving=shot;
    while(moving!=NULL)
    {
        if(moving->y>658) //ha eléri az alját
        {
            if(remaining==NULL)  //ha ez az első elem
            {
                shot=moving->next;
                free(moving);
                moving=shot->next;
            }else{

            remaining->next=moving->next;
            free(moving);
            moving=remaining->next;
            }
        }else{
            moving=moving->next;
        }

    }

    return shot;
}
```

When I call free, i get this error in Xcode:

> NHF(1670,0x7fff77e1a300) malloc: *** error for object 0x10050c9e0: pointer being freed was >not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

This is an SDL game, and this function is free the shot after it reaches the end of the map.

I gotta finish this to Sunday, but I'm stuck :(

Comment: you moved the pointer between the time it was created and when you attempted to free it. You are not showing enough code to allow a  test compile and run, so difficult to know for sure. But if you do something like `char *p = malloc(10);`, then... `p++;`, then... `free(p);` you will likely get the error you described.

Comment: What line in the pastebin are you getting the error you described?  ( _pointer being freed was >not allocated * set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug_ )  ***Have you followed the messages instruction?***

Comment: 121. the first free in function, what i wrote in the question

Comment: I tried. I get this:
http://i.imgur.com/elfSY8X.png

Comment: My answer below did not exactly address your specific issue.  I mis-stated the real issue I think.  Your real issue is simply that within the translation unit (function) you saw the error message, `moving` was created, assigned a value, then attempted to be freed without ever having calloc or malloc called to assign memory.  That simply is the reason for your error message I think.  Sorry for the confusion before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT 2***

Look at lines 110 and 113 in your code (pastebin). You create moving, then you set moving = shot, then you free moving on line 121. You never used `malloc()` or `calloc()` on it in that translation block. That is why you are getting your error. Don't free it in that translation block. You probably need to free shot in the calling function (or wherever it was given memory.)

***EDIT***
If in your code, you created `moving`,  then you changed `moving` to point to a different location than was returned originally, the problem would have been caused for a *different* reason.  See illustration:

```
char *string = {0};
string = calloc(10, 1);//see 1)
string++;//see 2)
free(string);//see 3)
```

***1)***  string may look like this in memory:

```
  0x000BCA00
 >|< (pointer position returned from calloc)
  |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
```

***2)***  pointer `string` is moved from its original position:

```
  0x000BCA04
         >|< (new ponter position)
  |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|8|
```

***3)***  0x000BCA00 != 0x000BCA04, therefore free() will not work

***End EDIT***

If you compile and run:

```
int main(void)
{

    char *p = malloc(10);
    p++;  //pointer is no longer what malloc returned, so free will not work
    free(p);fails here
    return 0;
}
```

You are likely to get the error message you described.
I get this one:

[image]

***Look through your code*** to identify similar conditions.  Better yet, follow your compiler error message's directions:  ***set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug***

Comment: i think i have something wrong in my linked list. My debuger tell me nothing, so i searching for it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @fzsombor - Look at lines 110 and 113 in your code. You create moving, then you set moving = shot, then you free moving on line 121.  You never used malloc or calloc on it in that translation block.  That is why you are getting your error.  Don't free it.  You probably need to free shot in the calling function (or wherever it was given memory.)

Comment: if you copy a pointer in a variable, and give the variable to free()
dont it gotta free the memory it pointed to?

Comment: You only ever use free on a pointer variable for which malloc, calloc or realloc has been used to initially allocate the memory. So, the answer is no, do not freemoving in that block :).

Comment: i need to free it when it collides. so i cant free it where i call the alloc, because that function, is only create shots.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug.

The value you pass to `free()` must be a value returned by `malloc()`, or one of the related functions.

I see you are modifying your `moving` variable, but I don't think I have enough context to tell you exactly what needs to be changed.

But the value you are passing to `free()` is apparently not the value returned by `malloc()`.

Comment: You told me, you didnt have enough context, so i send you a larger context so i hope you can find the tiny error, what my debuger, and me cant find for 2 hours. Its not my entire code.

Comment: What I told you is that stackoverflow is about putting together a complete question. Sorry, I having paying clients and I can't take time away from that work to debug your program. I would think it wouldn't be hard to debug the issue. I've told you what is causing it. You need to see where that happens.